# How to replace certain values in pandas Series with its previous value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series object `s` like this:

```
>>> s
date
2020-03-26    19.72
2020-03-27    19.75
2020-03-30    19.43
2020-03-31    19.69
2020-04-01       --
2020-04-06    20.03
2020-04-07    20.45
2020-04-08    21.00
2020-04-09       --
2020-04-10    20.96
2020-04-13    20.75
2020-04-14    21.23
Name: price, dtype: object

>>> s.values
array(['19.72', '19.75', '19.43', '19.69', '--', '20.03', '20.45',
       '21.00', '20.82', '20.96', '20.75', '21.23'], dtype=object)
```

How can I replace `--` with its previous value?

I mean I want `s` to be converted to this:

```
date
2020-03-26    19.72
2020-03-27    19.75
2020-03-30    19.43
2020-03-31    19.69
2020-04-01    19.69
2020-04-06    20.03
2020-04-07    20.45
2020-04-08    21.00
2020-04-09    21.00
2020-04-10    20.96
2020-04-13    20.75
2020-04-14    21.23
Name: price, dtype: object
```

The `--` that belongs to `2020-04-01` is replaced with `2020-03-31`'s value, which is `19.69`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace those `--` to `NaN` and just [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```
df.replace('--', float('nan')).ffill()

           date
2020-03-26  19.72
2020-03-27  19.75
2020-03-30  19.43
2020-03-31  19.69
2020-04-01  19.69
2020-04-06  20.03
2020-04-07  20.45
2020-04-08  21.00
2020-04-09  21.00
2020-04-10  20.96
2020-04-13  20.75
2020-04-14  21.23
```

Or you could also use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html), coercing those that cannot be case to float:

```
pd.to_numeric(df.date, errors='coerce').ffill()
```

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of `float('nan')`. Why do you convert `'nan'` to float? Can I use `numpy.nan`?

Comment: So that it is an actual NaN, not a string. You could similarly use `np.nan`